# Coloring a Map's region based on poll data using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

So I'm fairly new to python but I have experience with matplotlib and a fair share of graphing, and I'm trying to make a map similar to this: [image: maps of US electoral results] (where the shade indicates voting intensity) but for [Egypt's governates](https://www.egynews.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/123.jpg). I have the data on a csv, and I know how to parse it in python, I just want to know how I would go about displaying that data on a map.

Unfortunately, maps online are very low quality, and so I can make a photoshop redraw of it easily. I want to know how I would color each governate based on the data using python.

My first instinct is to have a picture of each governate on a png and then give each image a shade based on the data and then stack all the governate images. But that seems stupid. I will obviously need to number the governates, which isn't that hard, but I have no clue how to start displaying them graphically.

Comment: I am interested in this script. Where is the csv data file used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a suitable shapefile for the governates then you can use [cartopy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html), which interfaces to matplotlib.  I just downloaded the second file from [this page](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/egypt-administrative-boundaries-levels-0-3) to use in the following. I notice the regions aren't the same as those in your linked image, but it at least illustrates how it could work.

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

reader = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader('egy_admbnda_adm1_capmas_20170421.shp')

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([24, 38, 20, 33])

for i, geom in enumerate(reader.geometries()):
    ax.add_geometries([geom], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor=cmap(i * 10))

plt.show()
```

[image]